# Efficient way to map ids

Tags: bash, shell

I have two text files,

File 1 with data like

User game count

```
A Rugby 2
A Football 2
B Volleyball 1
C TT 2
...
```

File 2

```
1 Basketball
2 Football
3 Rugby
...
90 TT
91 Volleyball
...
```

Now what I want to do is add another column to File 2 such that I have the corresponding index of the game from File 2 as an extra column in File 1.

I have 2 million entries in File 1. So I want to add another column specifying the index(basically the line number or order) of the game from file 2. How can I do this efficiently.

Right now I am doing this line by line. Reading a line from file 1, grep the corresponding game from file 2 for its line number and saving/writing that to a file.

This will take me ages. How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{print $0,a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: I tried the script with 10 millions rows in file 2 and 3000 rows in file1 and it takes for ever. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: 10 million different sports? Are you sure you have the files in the right order? `1 Basketball/2 Football/3 Rugby/etc` first, `A Rugby 2/A Football 2/etc` second?

Answer (score 1):

Your File2 should have no records duplicated, such as no two football index records.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}$0=$0 FS a[$2]' file2 file1
```